# Drove 238 miles and used 27.3 litres of petrol: find upper bound for consumption per mile, considering measurement errors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, error-propagation

$X$ drove $238$ miles, correct nearest mile. They used $27.3$ litres of petrol, to the nearest tenth of a litre.

### $\text {Petrol Consumption} =$$\text {Miles}\over \text {Petrol Used}$

Work out the upper bound.

---

I used $238.5\over 27.35$ to get $8.72 (2dp)$

however the book states the answer is $8.75$

Am I wrong, and how? Or is it simply an error on the book's behalf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PetrolConsumption is maximized when PetrolUsed is *minimized*.

$$\frac{238.5}{27.25} \simeq 8.75 $$

Answer (score 0):

No the book is right.

You have to do 238.5 divided by 27.25 to get 8.75.

The reason is becuase you have to take the uppper bound of the number of miles travelled and the lower bound of litres of petrol to get the upper bound overall.